# Including PHP files doesn't work in Cron PHP Scripts (Ubuntu VPS)

Tags: php, cron, ubuntu-14.04, php-include

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 X64.

I am setting up a basic Cron job with `crontab -e`:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/test/test.php >> /var/www/cron/cron.log
```

This is /var/www/html/test/test.php:

```
<?php 
include "../test2.php"; 
?>
```

And /var/www/html/test2.php:

```
<?php 
echo "hello world"; 
?>
```

And yet nothing is being echoed. But when I go to [domain]/test/test.php, I do see "hello world" being echoed. Why am I not seeing it in `/var/www/cron/cron.log`?

Answer (score 1):

PHP and cronjobs can be a mess - especially when including other files. Try the following in your crontab:

```
* * * * * cd /var/www/html/test; /usr/bin/php test.php >> /var/www/cron/cron.log
```

Answer (score 1):

Try including the full path in the php include, and make it require instead of a include:

```
<?php 
  require_once("/var/www/html/test2.php"); 
?>
```

You can also set your include path:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-include-path.php

Comment: Thanks, this actually worked. So should I just set my include path in every PHP file I intend to run with cron? Would I then be able to use relative paths?

Comment: You should avoid using absolut path for just one reason: If for any reason the directory changes (move to a different hoster, using a different distri or whatever) you have to change it again in all your scripts.

Comment: You can solve it using a path like this: `__DIR__ . '/../test2.php';`

Answer (score 1):

Why don't use absolute path in the include?

```
<?php
    include __DIR__ . '/../test2.php';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you write a wrong directory in cron

```
/usr/bin/php /var/www/**html**/test/test.php
```

in test.php

```
/var/www/test/test.php
```

in www directory have a html directory?

Comment: Some servers use /var/www/html that is the default in RedHat's Apache configuration.

Comment: so why he dont put the file in /var/www/html/test/test.php

Comment: I made a mistake writing my question. It is corrected now, thanks for catching it.